# Juju could not add relation between mediawiki & mariadb

Tags: juju, aws

My Juju version is:

```
# juju --version
1.25.6-xenial-amd64
```

See attachment for wiki scalable.
Problem:

```
# juju-1 add-relation mediawiki mariadb
ERROR ambiguous relation: "mediawiki mariadb" could refer to "mediawiki:db mariadb:db"; "mediawiki:slave mariadb:db"
```

My deployments:

```
# juju-1 deploy haproxy --constraints 'instance-type=t2.micro'
Added charm "cs:trusty/haproxy-19" to the environment.
# juju-1 deploy mediawiki --constraints 'instance-type=t2.micro'
Added charm "cs:trusty/mediawiki-5" to the environment.
# juju-1 add-relation haproxy mediawiki
# juju-1 deploy mariadb --constraints 'instance-type=t2.micro'
Added charm "cs:trusty/mariadb-3" to the environment.
```

What did I do wrong couldn't add relation between mediawiki & mariadb.
[image]

Comment: Samething happened on realtime syslog analytics deployment:                   root@ubuntu:~# juju-1 deploy realtime-syslog-analytics --constraints 'instance-type=t2.micro'
ERROR cannot resolve charm URL "cs:trusty/realtime-syslog-analytics": charm not found
root@ubuntu:~#

Comment: The with syslog-analytics is a different issue. I can help you with that if you create a new question for that issue and link it here.

Comment: can you also link the page from the screenshot? It seems the instructions are incomplete so I want to report that.

Comment: @Galgalesh Thank you.  I will try 1st issue with your solution tomorrow.  I will create new for 2nd issue later today.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

> ERROR ambiguous relation: "mediawiki mariadb" could refer to "mediawiki:db mariadb:db"; "mediawiki:slave mariadb:db"

This means that there are two types of relations possible between mediawiki and mariadb:

1. `mediawiki:db mariadb:db` used for connecting Mediawiki to a database.
2. `mediawiki:slave mariadb:db` used for connecting Mediawiki to a secundary (slave) database. See [the MediaWiki charm](https://jujucharms.com/mediawiki/trusty) for more information *(in the "MySQL Slave" section of that page).*

You have to specify which relation you want. `mediawiki:db mariadb:db` is the correct relationship for this example. Run the following command:

```
juju add-relation mediawiki:db mariadb:db
```

Comment: @StevePe Awesome! Please accept this answer (click the v next to this answer).